# content_for for xml.builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-builder

Is it possible to use content_for in *.xml.builder files?

when I print:

```
content_for :part do 
  xml.child "anything"
end

xml.parent do 
  xml << yield(:part) if content_for? :part
end
```

it returns

`<child>anything</child>
<parent>
  <child>anything</child>
</parent>`

But I need only

`<parent>
  <child>anything</child>
</parent>`

Comment: I am not familiar with xml builder so bear with me, but looking at the code it seems like `content_for` generates a `<child>anything</child>` node but already appends it to your `<parent>` element. Since you do an additional `xml << yield(:part)` it probably appends it again, but then at the root. What happens if you just do `yield(:part)`, i.e., without the `xml <<` part?

Comment: probably it was fixed anytime ago. as content_for does not return anything now

Comment: no. I hop to it, it is a still problem. If just yield(:part) is called, there is no content in parent block